# moving 2TB files from on-premises to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Our old infrastructure was hosted on an on-premises server, and now we are moving forward into Google Cloud Storage.  The problem is, my outgoing server connection is pretty slow, any ideas about syncing my files from on-premises with cloud storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have limited bandwidth, you can follow the instructions in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/on-prem-overview). The document provides you answer to the questions like:

Why should I use Transfer service for on-premises data?
I have limited bandwidth. Can I use Transfer service for on-premises data?

The way this works according to the document is through the following steps:

The following is a high-level overview of how Transfer service for on-premises data works:

1. Install Docker and run a small piece of software, called an agent, in your private data center. The agent runs within a Docker container and has access to your locally mounted NFS data.

See Installing and running the on-premises agent for more information.

2. Complete Transfer for on-premises first-time setup.
3. Start a Transfer service for on-premises data transfer from the Google Cloud Console. You'll provide the NFS directory and a destination Cloud Storage bucket to transfer data to.

See Creating a transfer job for more information.

4. When the transfer starts, it recursively traverses through the given NFS directory and moves data it finds to your Cloud Storage bucket.

Transferred data is checksummed, files with errors are re-tried, and data is sent via a secure connection. A record of the transfer's progress is written to log objects within your destination Cloud Storage bucket. You can track the progress of the transfer within the Google Cloud Console.

5. When the transfer completes, you can view error samples within the Google Cloud Console. You can also review the transfer log for a catalog of files transferred and any errors.

In the document, you can find more detail and the extra steps required.

Answer (score 2):

Check if [transfer-appliance](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-transfer-appliance-sneakernet-for-the-cloud-era) is an option:

> Transfer Appliance is a rackable high-capacity storage server that you set up in your data center. Fill it up with data and then ship it to us, and we upload your data to Google Cloud Storage. With capacity of up to one-petabyte compressed, Transfer Appliance helps you migrate your data orders-of-magnitude faster than over a typical network.

Comment: It's a good idea, but it seems like overkill for just 2TB of data.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the problem is the slow network on my on-premises server, is that solution fit for my need ?

Comment: It's definitely overkill. But I have seen organizations using similar sized snowballs for transfers to AWS in such scenarios. We weren't happy about it but still cheaper than sending someone with an NAS to the data center to bring the data to a location with a better uplink.

Comment: When analyzing the cost of an appliance, consider the transfer costs of doing over the Internet transfers.